# How to properly display a photo in a custom page template using ACF?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm just creating a custom page template in Wordpress using the ACF plugin. I have a problem displaying a photo on it. In the ACF field settings, I used the "URL" option as the returned format. unfortunately, but it doesn't work. I'm sending the code below. Can anyone help me ?

```
<div class="px-lg-4 bits-img-folder">
    <img src="<?php the_field('sixth_image');?>" alt="" class="bits-img rounded border bg-white">
</div>
```

Comment: I will add one more information that the technique I use works when they add it in the post template. But why not in the page template anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the field!

`
" alt="" class="bits-img rounded border bg-white">

`

Something like that!

Hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I've tried it before.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the code you are using? Maybe there is something wrong in the code?